# Access external database from Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have a Kubernetes (v1.18.6) with 1 service (loadbalancer), 2 pods in a development:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: app
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 6000
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

A network policy to access Internet (it is necessary for me):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: internet-access
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      networking/allow-internet-access: "true"
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - {}
```

Deployment config file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 120
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myregistrykey
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: app
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

It is working correctly. But now, I want to connect this imagen to an external database (in another network only access by internet). For this proposition I use this service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgresql
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 25060


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: postgresql
subsets:
  - addresses:
        - ip: 206............
    ports:
      - port: 25060
        name: postgresql
```

It is all the services:

```
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
app-service         LoadBalancer   10.245.134.137   206...........   6000:31726/TCP   2d4h
kubernetes          ClusterIP      10.245.0.1       <none>           443/TCP          3d7h
postgresql          ClusterIP      None             <none>           25060/TCP        19h
```

But when I try to connect I receive a timeout error of the database, like can't connect to the database.

I have an internet connection in the image.

**I find the solution, the problem was the rules of inbound of the database. I must add the IP of Kubernetes.**

Thx.

Comment: Can you share more details and your configuration YAMLs for reproducing purpose? Does you deployment also have selector `app: app`? It might be typo there. What K8s version are you using? You have 2 separate clusters (1 with kubernetes, 1 with PosgreSQL)? Is it possible to provide logs?

Comment: @PjoterS Hi, yes, I update the question.

Comment: Any reason you want to use a `Service`, and not use the PostgreSQL database server IP (`206....`) and port (`25060`) directly from your application / pods? Also, as a best practice, you might want to consider configuring SSL to encrypt the traffic between your kubernetes cluster and the external database server - see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ssl-tcp.html .

Comment: @BogdanL But I think that If I use the IP directly, I will have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe, please try it and let us know.

Comment: Please provide your deployent YAML and K8s version.

Comment: @FranciscoGonzalez where did you get the proper IP address to add to your inbound rules?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me:

Define a service , but set `clusterIP: None` , so no endpooint is created.

And then create an endpoint yourself with the SAME NAME as your service and set the IP and port of your db.

In your example , you have a type in your endpoint: the name of your endpoint is postgresql not postgresSql.

My example:

```
---
service.yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backend-mobile-db-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 5984
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backend-mobile-db-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
        - ip: 192.168.1.50
    ports:
      - port: 5984
        name: backend-mobile-db-service
```

Comment: Can you post your updated configuration ? Also , when you run "kubectl get services" does everything run smoothly ?

Comment: Is it possible to use this `endpoint` in the `.env` file of the application that we deployed on the `kubernetes` cluster? something like this: 

`DB_ADDRESS=backend-mobile-db-service`

Answer (score 3):

For better visibility I am placing the answer OP mentioned in question:

> I find the solution, the problem was the rules of inbound of the database. I must add the IP of Kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have your cluster with application on `Digital Ocean` cloud and your `PostgreSQL` is outside this cluster.

In your `Application Deployment` <> `application service` you have used [services with selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) so you didn't need to create `Endpoints` manually.

In your `external database service` you have used [services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) so you had to create `Endpoint` manually.

As database is `external service`, using `clusterIP: None` is pointless as it will try to match pods inside the cluster. I guess you added it as you read in [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services).

Last thing is that in `Endpoint` you set `ip: 206...` which is the same as application service `LoadBalancer` ip?

```
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
app-service         LoadBalancer   10.245.134.137   206...........   6000:31726/TCP   2d4h

subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 206............
```

It is only a part of information so I am guessing. However in this part you should provide IP of desired `database`, not your application `Loadbalancer` IP.

Now based on scenario you can connect:

- Database outside cluster with IP address
- Remotely hosted database with URI
- Remotely hosted database with URI and port remapping

Detailed information about above scenarios you can find in [Kubernetes best practices: mapping external services](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services)

Based on your current config I assume you want to use `scenario 1`.

If this `database` and `cluster` are somewhere in cloud you could use `internal Database IP`. If not you should provide IP of machine where this Database is hosted.

You can also read [Kubernetes Access External Services](https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-access-external-services-e4fd643e5097) article.

Please let me know if you will still have issue after IP change

Answer (score 0):

The service definition should be corrected. Default service type is clusterIP which doesn't work for external database. You need to update the service type as given below

type: ExternalName

also ensure that service name and the endpoint name should match. it is different in your yaml. please check