# How to connect a Kubernetes cluster to and external SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I have a running Kubernetes cluster running multiple nodes. I want to connect my application (built on .Net) to an external SQL Server.

My connection string Looks like this

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server= 192.168.2.68; database=ArcadiaAuthenServiceDB;user id=pbts;password=exTened;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
},
```

I was able to connect to DB Environment by whitelisting each node IP to allow connection to the external SQL Server.

I can successfully telnet DB IP and port.

I added this `Server= 192.168.2.68; database=ArcadiaAuthenServiceDB;user id=pbts;password=exTened;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` to configmap on K8s

In my `service.YAML deployment I added the configmap as an environmental variable. And was able to connect.

Instead of using configmap I'd love to use secrets, how can I achieve this?

However, I know this connection isn't secured enough. What best practice can I use to achieve this connectivity.

How can I ensure that I do not have to always whitelist node IP if I choose to increase k8s nodes?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mssql-config
  namespace: dev
data:
  database_uri: Server= 192.168.2.68; database=ArcadiaAuthenServiceDB;user id=pbts;password=exTened;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Environmental Variables

```
env:
          - name: Logging__LogLevel__Default
            value: Debug
          - name: Logging__LogLevel__Microsoft.AspNetCore
            value: Debug
          - name: ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: mssql-config
                key: database_uri
```

Comment: So the actual question has nothing to do with SQL Server. Have you checked [Access external database from Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63344920/access-external-database-from-kubernetes)

Comment: The `192.168.0.0/16` CIDR block is a private non-routable address range. You can telnet to the DB IP and port but... are your k8s cluster and all of its nodes located in the same CIDR block?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I do not understand much about networking, However, I was able to reach the DB from one of my worker nodes using sqlcmd

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes you are right, I'm beginning to think its my code not using the ENV set in my deployment yaml file.